# mysql determining which part of a query is the slowest

Tags: mysql

I've written a select statement in mySQL.  The duration is **50** seconds, and the fetch is **206** seconds.  This is a long time.  I'd like to **understand** WHICH part of my query is inefficient so I can improve its run time, but I'm not sure how to do that in mySQL.

My table has a little over 1,000,000 records.  I have an index built in as well:

```
KEY `idKey` (`id`,`name`),
```

Here is my query:

```
SELECT name, id, alt_id, count(id), min(cost), avg(resale), code from
 history where name like "%brian%" group by id;
```

I've looked at the mySQL Execution Plan, but I can't garner from that what is wrong:

[image]

If I highlight over the "Full Index Scan" part of the image, I see this:

```
Access Type: Index
    Full Index Scan
Key/Index:
   Used Key Parts: id, name
   Possible Keys: idKey, id-Key, nameKey
Attach Condition:
   (`allhistory`.`history`.`name` LIKE '%brian%')

Rows Examined Per Scan: 1098181
Rows Produced Per Join: 1098181
Filter: 100%
```

I know I can just scan a smaller subset of data by adding a `LIMIT 100` into the query, and while it makes the time much shorter, *(28 second duration, 0.000 sec Fetch,)* I also want to see all the records - so I don't really want to put a limit on it.

Can someone more knowledgeable on this topic suggest where my query, my index, or my methodology might be inefficient for what I'm trying to accomplish?

Comment: `like "%brian%" ` full table/index scan. Reason: **NON-SARGABLE** expression. Think about phone book it is easy to find `brain%`, go to page B - C and search. With `%brain%` search entire phone book it will take ages :D

Comment: Does it have to be `%brian%`?  If there is an index on `name`, it could be used if the search were `brian%`.

Comment: Oh ok - so by using the wildcard I force the search to ignore my index - is that what "full table scan" means?

Comment: Using `%` at begining you force to full index scan, but still you can use wildcard at the end

Comment: perhaps you can embrace the potential power and likely misery of mysql [FULLTEXT search](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/fulltext-search.html)

Comment: The thing is - I need to allow my users to search `by keyword` not just be unique record number or something definite.  There has to be a way for me to be able to do that without having a 6 minute execution time....

Comment: check out my answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/30677347) for a 2 minute view of full text search

Comment: WHY would someone downvote?  If this isn't an example of what Stackoverflow itself considers a good question: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask I don't know what is........

Comment: @Drew Let me test it out and see how it works :)

Comment: Brian, some times you have to deal with people in rotten moods. Can one find a more opinionated lot than programmers?  :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This question has a solution only in mysql full text search functionality.

I don't consider the use of `like` a workable solution. Table scans are not a solution with millions of rows.

I wrote up an answer in this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30677347), I hope you find a workable solution for yours with that reference and quick walk thru.

Here is one of the Mysql Manual Pages on [Full Text Search](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/fulltext-natural-language.html).

Comment: Does my inclusion of a `like` statement automatically force a full table scan?  Does the term `full table scan` mean that any index I've created is being ignored?  Sorry for the noob questions...

Comment: the first comment under your question from @lad2025 describes it well. As for your second question, it the db engine has to perform a full table scan, it means it tried to use indexes in place, and abandoned such fruitful efforts, and plods thru every row

Comment: check out [mysql explain syntax](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/explain.html). It won't run the query (with explain plopped in front of it). It will show you the db plan quickly

Comment: Beautiful.  This really helps me understand.  Thank you Drew!

Comment: you're welcome. Good luck. Results will come back fast. The *Quality* of the results is yet to be determined !

Answer (score 1):

I'm thinking your covered index may be backwards.  Try switching the order (name, id).  That way the WHERE clause can take advantage of the index.

Comment: not gonna downvote but this is way out there in left field

Comment: I don't think so.  The order of the covered index is important.

Comment: this has nothing to do with covered indexes