# Can MySQL search ignore HTML tags

Tags: mysql, wordpress

I have a WordPress site using a search plugin called Relevanssi. Relevanssi's search is MySQL based; which means that Relevanssi searches the database tables when a query is made on the front-end of my site.

The issue I have (and I've contacted Relevanssi's developer about this, who has no idea how to fix this) is that when I search for a sentence, and this sentence includes italicized or bolded text in the actual WordPress page, Relevanssi returns a "No Results Found" page.

Example: If I search for, "described in the course as if it has two parts" I get no results, because the actual phrase on the website is, "described in the course as if it has two parts" -- the "as if" is in italics.

So I think what's happening is that the Relevanssi MySQL-based search cannot find this example phrase, because the code for this phrase looks like this: `described in the course <i>as if</i> it has two parts`

So the search gets "hung up" on the `<i>` (and other HTML) tags.

Using Relevanssi's (premium version) version offers a search using "Custom MySQL columns to index" but this isn't an option for me because it's going to double the size of my database which is already huge. So, I'm wondering if there's a way to have MySQL ignore or filter out `<i>`, `<em>`, `<strong>` tags, etc. - essentially just skipping them in the search, as if they are invisible. Thank you.

Comment: Is fulltext search an option for you?

Comment: @Drew, thank you, can you explain that more? I'm really not very familiar with MySQL.

Comment: I am not exactly fluent on it because the functionality is tricky. It depends on your mysql version and whether or not you are using innodb or myisam. [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/30677347) is one small write-up I did.

Comment: Hi, I just checked the tables in my database; the ones relevant to my question are MyISAM.

Comment: Fulltext search in particular full text indexes only somewhat recently became implemented on innodb. Prior, it was a myisam thing iirc. I can only imagine that with the lucky enough [search](https://wordpress.org/support/topic/mysql-full-text-search) you are close to finding an answer