# Can InnoDB use a stopword file?

Tags: mysql, innodb, myisam, stop-words

With fulltext search for MyISAM, I know that I can specify a stopword file in my.cnf with the following:

```
ft_stopword_file = '/etc/stopword.txt'
```

Can the same also be done with fulltext search for InnoDB? I'd like to do something like the following if possible:

```
ft_stopword_file_innodb = '/etc/stopword.txt'
```

However, I haven't seen any documentation indicating that stopwords for InnoDB can be stored in a file.

Answer (score 2):

No, it cannot natively, hotwired, use a text file out of the box. That is, mysql as shipped. To achieve that you would need to write speciality UDF's which would be absurd considering the simple solution.

The information for custom Stop Words usage is available on this mysql [manual page](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/fulltext-stopwords.html). It shows the rather limited default words out of the gates in the table `INFORMATION_SCHEMA.INNODB_FT_DEFAULT_STOPWORD`, how to reset to your own table, and the use of various system variables.

Comment: Wait. What? They put stuff like that in the MySQL Reference Manual? +10.

Comment: It was a pathetic answer. My favorite FT search answer is from you spencer. I know one of yours once turned me on to the Natural Language thing. My answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/30677347). Still can't believe you only got 3 upvotes for yours linked at the bottom @spencer7593

Comment: It's good answer... one of the politest "RTFM" answers I've ever seen.

Comment: Thanks. There are some gems tucked away in the pile of dung which SO has become. Try searching for an answer to a question.. and you'll encounter what I refer to as a "great wall of crap". It's no wonder that noobs don't search for answers before flinging more excrement onto the heap. (It seems that SO measures its "progress" by its increasing stench, rather than any decrease in the size of feculent mound).

Comment: For InnoDB, the link you posted gives examples of stopwords in a MySQL table, but not a text file.

Comment: That is the way it manages it. Something under its control. Do you need assistance with `load data infile` to bring it in?