# relevance score of MATCH..AGAINST is not working (MySql)

Tags: mysql

Relevance score of MATCH..AGAINST is not working.

Created one dummy table which has 2 rows.

Dummy Table

Row1=> 'Leela Hayat Marriot'

Row2=> 'Americas Best Value'

**Query1:**

SELECT MATCH (col1) AGAINST ('Leela* Hayat*' IN BOOLEAN MODE) AS relevance 
FROM table1 
WHERE MATCH (col1) AGAINST ('Leela* Hayat*' IN BOOLEAN MODE);

Result:

relevance

2

**Query2:**

SELECT MATCH (col1) AGAINST ('Americas* Best*' IN BOOLEAN MODE) AS relevance 
FROM table1 
WHERE MATCH (col1) AGAINST ('Americas* Best*' IN BOOLEAN MODE);

Result:

relevance

1

Query1 is working fine but why is query 2 not working?

Why am I getting relevance 1 instead of 2 in Query2 as Americas and Best both are present in column.

Thanks

Comment: show your schema create. Tell us your mysql version.

Comment: @Drew: 
CREATE TABLE `table1` (
  `col1` varchar(500) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

=====================================

INSERT INTO `table1` (col1) VALUES
('Leela Hayat Marriot'),
('Americas Best Value');

=====================================
ALTER TABLE `table1` ADD FULLTEXT KEY `col1` (`col1`);
========================
Mysql Version: 5.5.46
======================
Sorry for unformatted comment

Answer (score 0):

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/fulltext-stopwords.html

'BEST' is listed in stopword list.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_ft_stopword_file

**ft_stopword_file:**

The file from which to read the list of stopwords for full-text searches on MyISAM tables. The server looks for the file in the data directory unless an absolute path name is given to specify a different directory. All the words from the file are used; comments are not honored. By default, a built-in list of stopwords is used (as defined in the storage/myisam/ft_static.c file). Setting this variable to the empty string ('') disables stopword filtering.

I disabled stopwords list and now query 2 is working fine.

Thanks for help.

Comment: A few I wrote up: [1](http://stackoverflow.com/a/30677347) and [2](http://stackoverflow.com/a/37604988) depending if you want MyISAM or INNODB