# mysql search by multiple words

Tags: php, mysql, sql

how can i make a search in mysql by multiple words. Let's say i have a title "black handbag for womans". my search string is "handbag womans". I want to display all the products that have handbag and womans in title. I did an sql,it search the products that have handbag and womans but also products that only have handbag or womans, i want just those that have both words.

```
 $stmt = $dbh->prepare("SELECT * FROM Produse  
                        INNER JOIN Categorii on Produse.ID_Categorie=Categorii.ID_Categorie 
                       where MATCH Produse.Prod_Name  AGAINST ('$q' IN BOOLEAN MODE) order by Produse.Prod_Name  ASC");
        $stmt->execute();
```

Comment: Mysql give you Like() operator for the task. Check this link http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_like.asp

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/30677347 , I have a similar answer floating around for innodb

Answer (score 0):

Try this way This is for mysql query

```
SELECT     *
FROM       produse
INNER JOIN categorii
ON         produse.id_categorie=categorii.id_categorie
WHERE      produse.prod_name LIKE '%$q%'
ORDER BY   produse.prod_name ASC
```

Comment: if i use `'%q%'` it'll not work if another word is between my string search

Comment: Try `'%$q%'` not `'%q%'` please check is it proper ?