# How do I create a MySQL query using an array?

Tags: mysql, ruby, arrays

I need to take an array and use it for a MySQL query.

I tried looking for methods but all of them seem to be related to PHP arrays and not Ruby.

For example, I have `terms = ['genetics', 'elderly', 'health']` and I want to use:

```
con.query "SELECT col1 FROM data1 WHERE MATCH (col2) AGAINST (terms)"
```

Is this possible?

Comment: need more information. Give some examples.

Comment: So, for example I have 
 terms = ['genetics' , 'elderly', 'health']
and I want to use
con.query "SELECT col1 FROM data1 WHERE MATCH (col2) AGAINST (terms)"
is this possible?

Comment: what you have,I can't see.

Comment: sorry, accidentally pressed enter too early!

Comment: I don't understand your problem. is it mysql related or ruby array related?

Comment: I guess more mysql related. Whenever I try to use a ruby array to define what I want to query my database with, Mysql returns with nothing, even though I know the elements of the ruby array are present in my database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just `join` your terms in your `against` clause:

```
terms = ['genetics' , 'elderly', 'health']
con.query "SELECT col1 FROM data1 WHERE MATCH col2 AGAINST ('#{terms.join(' ')}')"
```

Note that using `match/against` will almost certainly be more performative than using a series of `like` clauses. See this StackOverflow answer for more information: [Which SQL query is better, MATCH AGAINST or LIKE?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/792875/which-sql-query-is-better-match-against-or-like).

Check out the MySQL documentation for more information on full text searching (including possible operators): http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/fulltext-search.html.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! I did try this but it returned nothing. If it helps, the col2 is text with each row having a paragraph, not just one word. I'm not sure if that is why this is so troublesome

I was able to get some results, but only from this: 
terms = ['genetics']
   _terms = terms.map{|x| "'" + x + "'"}.join(',')
    
    rs= con.query "SELECT col1 FROM data1 WHERE MATCH col2 against (#{_terms})"

as you can see, I can only get a result when the array has one element...

Comment: It's not necessary to use `<del>` tags if you need to change your answer. Stack Overflow maintains a history of your edits so we'd be able to see the changes if need-be.

Answer (score 0):

I'd highly recommend looking into an ORM, such as [Sequel](http://sequel.rubyforge.org/), which makes it very easy to generate the proper query in a DBM independent way.

It allows us to use arrays and hashes conveniently. Here's [an example](http://sequel.rubyforge.org/rdoc/files/README_rdoc.html) using an array to generate the "where" clause in SQL:

```
my_posts = posts.where(:category => ['ruby', 'postgres', 'linux'])
# WHERE category IN ('ruby', 'postgres', 'linux')
```

That particular example is part of the "Filtering Records" section.

In a comment, the OP said:

> col2 is text with each row having a paragraph, not just one word.

Then you want a `LIKE` or regex clause that allows each word to be tested. See the "[String search functions](http://sequel.rubyforge.org/rdoc/files/doc/dataset_filtering_rdoc.html)" section of "Dataset Filtering " for how Sequel allows you to search inside strings.

The code would be something like:

```
data1.select(:col1).where(Sequel.like(:col2, terms.map{ |t| "%#{ t }%" } ))
```

which would generate something like:

```
SELECT col1 FROM data1 WHERE ((col2 LIKE '%genetics%') OR (col2 LIKE '%elderly%') OR (col2 LIKE '%health%'))
```

Comment: Check out @howluocanyougo's comment on my answer, which suggests that s/he wants to do a full index search, not a `where/in` query. My initial answer, which you deleted, said pretty much the same thing you say above (using AR instead of Sequel).

Comment: Your original answer is still there. You can rollback to it by clicking on the "edited" link. At that point I'd recommend merging the original answer with your updated answer to show both, along with a quote of the OP's comment to clarify why you added the new content.

Comment: thanks for the suggestion! kardeiz actually was correct in what I was looking for but I'll definitely look into Sequel!