# Full text search leading plus not working properly

Tags: mysql

I'm having trouble with the match against function. When I run the following query :

```
    SELECT 
        i.name,
        n.trad,
        i.icon_name,
        i.quality
    FROM strings_item AS n
        LEFT JOIN items AS i ON n.name = i.description
    WHERE match(n.body_en) against ('+cat*+queen*' IN BOOLEAN MODE)
```

It returns rows that contains cat OR queen. Isn't + supposed to return rows containing both words?

Edit:

Here are some examples of data it returns :

```
Cataclysm's Jaws
Catalium
Catalium Rod
Grand Master's Gleaming Catalium Dagger
```

And it seems like it never returns anything with queen. So, I tried to change the matching word to '+cat +queen' and here is what it displayed :

```
Iceheart Queen's Shield
Queen Klaw's Pauldrons
[Playing Card] Queen of Hearts
Cat Queen Egg
Cat Queen Box
```

PS: I kept these words in the same order as in mysql and the row I'm looking for is the Cat Queen Egg

Comment: It should work like you expect. Can you try to add a blank between +cat* and +queen*

Comment: It returns no result when I put a blank between these two words.

Comment: This link might help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/792875/which-sql-query-is-better-match-against-or-like

Comment: When you suffix  `*` data with then it will look data as `cats,cate,cati...` etc and same for queen. Not sure what you are getting but some sample data would be good to diagnose the  issue.

Comment: Your query seems to be correct after adding a `blank space` like `+cat* +queen*`. Does your database contains a row that have both `cat` and `queen` in it?

Comment: I've edited the question. Yes, there is a row containing both : Cat Queen Egg. However, when I try +cat* +queen*, it returns nothing :/

Comment: Well in your second matching query `+cat +queen` it is ingnoring `cat` as it is a 3 letter word and sql ignores them. Check ` ft_min_word_len` settings You will get the same result if you look for `queen` only. Just try `+cat* +queen`

Comment: got your problem, just enter a row `category is queen` and try your match `+cat* +queen*`.  It will return this row only. what's happening is, your database have a row `cat queen egg`. Sql do not take `cat` in its full index search as `cat` is too small. That is why you get nothing returned at present

Comment: I tried +cat* +queen, it returned nothing. However, when I changed ft_min_word_len settings to 2, it worked fine. Thank you :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your query is correct. Your database do not have a row that contains both `cat*` and `queen*`.

By default the `ft_min_word_len` has a value of 4 in sql. (https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_ft_min_word_len).

Therefore sql do not take words less than 4 characters in its full-text index.

eg:

```
Instructions      1
are               2
applicable        3
to                4
these             5
Adventure         6
```

In this row, sql will not take words 2,3 and 4 in its full-text index.

Either change your `ft_min_word_len` or add rows that contains word of more than 4 characters that contains `cat` in it.

Just to add here you can find a list of `stop words` that are also ignored in full-text index. http://mssqltipsandtricks.blogspot.de/2012/07/noisestop-words-in-sql-server.html